# Conflicting information on the 8042 status byte

Tags: assembly, keyboard, x86-16

Bits zero and one of the 8042 status byte have to be in a certain state when reading or writing bytes from ports 60h, and 64h.

I have found conflicting information pertaining to these bits.

Page 1160 of this [pdf](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~pannain/mc404/aulas/pdfs/Art%20Of%20Intel%20x86%20Assembly.pdf) says, "Before writing any data to these ports (60h, and 64h), bit zero of port 64h must be zero; data is available for reading from port 60h when bit one of port 64h contains a one."

However the roles of these bits are reversed on the [osdev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller).

According to osdev, bit zero must be set before attempting to read data from port 60h, and bit one must be cleared before attempting to write data to port 60h or 64h.

So which is correct?

Osdev seems to be specifically referring to a PS/2 controller, while the pdf refers to a classic 8042. Were these bits reversed in the PS/2 keyboard controller?

I wrote some code based on the pdf's description of the bits. Its intended to disable the keyboard by masking the interrupt enable, and keyboard disable bits in the 8042 command byte.

This doesn't work at all in DOSBox regardless of whether I swap the roles of the bits or not. Maybe DOSBox doesn't simulate an 8042?

It does seem to work on hardware (old pentium laptop running DOS), but I have to comment out the delay before reading port 60h. Neither bit one or bit zero are ever set, so it just loops forever. Maybe there is no need to delay a port 60h read on more modern hardware.

```
KBD_CMD:
    in al, 64h 
    test al, 1
    jnz KBD_CMD       ;wait for cleared bit 0 to write to port 64h 


    mov al, 20h       ;al <- request 8042 command byte command
    out 64h, al       ;command byte will now be available at port 60h




KBD_CMD_0:
    in al, 64h 
    test al, 10b
    jz KBD_CMD_0      ;wait for set bit 1 to read port 60h     


    in al, 60h        ;al <- existing command byte
    and al, 11111110b
    or al, 00010000b  ;disable keyboard and interrupt mask.
    mov ah, al        ;store new command byte mask




KBD_CMD_1:
    in al, 64h 
    test al, 1
    jnz KBD_CMD_1     ;wait for cleared bit 0 to write to port 64h 

    mov al, 60h       ;al <- send command byte to 8042 command
    out 64h, al       ;next byte written to port 60h will be new comand byte




KBD_CMD_2:
    in al, 64h 
    test al, 1
    jnz KBD_CMD_2     ;wait for cleared bit 0 to write to port 60h 

    mov al, ah        ;al <- new command byte mask
    out 60h, al       ;keyboard should be disabled
```

I would appreciate an example of how to correctly collect, mask, then send the 8042's command byte.

Comment: I have to look up which is which (i'm not on my desktop so hard to look things up). But often the confusion in documentation (and there is bad code out there) was in terminology. Send buffer and receive (or output/input) buffer for example... if you look at it from the perspective of the controller send and receive (output and input) mean one thing and seen from the computer it is the reverse. This lead to confusing and misleading tutorials that got the meanings backwards. The 8042 manual for example likely uses terminology from the perspective of the controller.

Comment: Appears OSDEv is correct. When writing to port 0x60 or 0x64 you have to wait until bit 1 becomes 0 on port 0x64 (status register). Before reading a character from 0x60 you need to wait until bit 0 of port 0x64 (status register) is set (1).

Comment: Checking a datasheet for an old Super I/O chip (IT8712F) also confirms that OSDev is correct. Note that normally you don't use either these status bits. You just read port 0x60 whenever you get a keyboard interrupt. as the OSDev page explains.

Comment: I don't normally bother with the status bits when i'm just polling port 60h for scancodes, but dont you have to use them when you actually want to program the 8042?

Comment: If you are using interrupts (which you are not) then you do not have to wait for bit 0 to become set before reading a character in your interrupt handler. You are polling, and in that case you do need  to wait for bit 0 to become set(1) before reading a character from port 0x60.

Comment: When done properly BOCHs does work even when polling. Many issues come on newer hardware that simulate the keyboard controller through SMM(System Management Mode) and often that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Do you think there's any chance you could give me a code snippet of the proper way to send a new command byte to the 8042?